# Group of order 15 is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

How do I prove that a group of order 15 is abelian?

Is there any general strategy to prove that a group of particular order (composite order) is abelian?

Comment: Sylow's theorems for showing that the group is the direct product of its Sylow subgroups, then apply that every group of order $p$ or $p^2$ is abelian. That's the general strategy for small order groups.

Comment: A belated +1 for the second sentence in your question.  In the study of finite groups, I think such inquiries make the difference between busy work and real mathematics.

Comment: Yes, there's a simple one based on the class equation, as soon as $p\nmid q-1$ (which is the case if $p=3$ and $q=5$). See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4394327/1007416

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Let $G$ be a group of order 15.  We know $G$ has subgroups of order 3 and order 5, say $P_3$ and $P_5$ from Sylow theory.  These must be cyclic (why?) so write $P_3 = \langle a \rangle$, $P_5 = \langle b \rangle$.

Using the lemma below, show $G = P_3P_5$.  Prove the lemma if it's not something you already know.

**Lemma.** For subgroups $H$ and $K$ of a finite group $G$, $|HK| = |H||K|/ |H \cap K|$, where $HK = \{hk \mid h \in H, k \in K\}$.

Using Sylow theory, show $P_3$ is normal.

Then $bab^{-1} \in \langle a \rangle$.  If $bab^{-1} = a$, we have $ba = ab$, so $G$ is abelian.  Observe $bab^{-1} \neq 1$ (why?).  The only "bad" possibility now is that $bab^{-1} = a^2$.

Suppose, to get a contradiction, that $bab^{-1} = a^2$.  Then $ba = a^2b$.  Using this identity repeatedly to fill in the $ \cdots $, show $a = b^5a = \cdots = a^2b^5 = a^2$.  But $a \neq a^2$, so this is a contradiction.

PS - Since $P_3$ and $P_5$ are both normal, you could instead argue that $G = P_3P_5$ implies $G \simeq P_3 \times P_5$.  In general, you can adapt this argument to show for primes $p,q$ with $p > q$ and $q \nmid p - 1$, every group of order $pq$ is abelian.

Comment: Hi, I have one concern at the moment, say I have $A$, and $B$ are 2 normal subgroups of $G$, and $A \cap B = \{ e \}$. Will I always have that $AB \cong A \times B$?

Comment: As someone who has no background in group theory: What does $G=P_3P_5$ mean (better: how is it defined)? Is this some kind of combination of groups?

Comment: Knowing $P_3$ is normal, it must be a union of conjugacy classes. Since the order of each conjugacy class is a divisor of 15, the only possibility is $3=1+1+1$, which implies $P_3$ is in the centre.

Answer (score 47):

[Here](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/nilpotentnumbers.pdf) is a 2000 paper of Pakianathan and Shankar which gives characterizations of the set of positive integers $n$ such that every group of order $n$ is (i) cyclic, (ii) abelian, or (iii) nilpotent.

Say that a positive integer $n > 1$ is a **nilpotent number** if $n = p_1^{a_1} \cdots p_r^{a_r}$ (here the $p_i$'s are distinct prime numbers) and for all $1 \leq i,j \leq r$ and $1 \leq k \leq a_i$, $p_i^k \not \equiv 1 \pmod{p_j}$.  Also, let us say that $1$ is a nilpotent number.

(So, for instance, any prime power is a nilpotent number.  A product of two distinct primes $pq$ is a nilpotent number unless $p \equiv 1 \pmod q$ or $q \equiv 1 \pmod p$.)

Then, for $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$:

(i) (Pazderski, 1959) Every group of order $n$ is nilpotent iff $n$ is a nilpotent number.
(ii) (Dickson, 1905) Every group of order $n$ is abelian iff $n$ is a cubefree nilpotent number.
(iii) (Szele, 1947) Every group of order $n$ is cyclic iff $n$ is a squarefree nilpotent number.

For example, if $n = pq$ is a product of distinct primes, then $n$ is squarefree, so every group of order $n$ is nilpotent iff every group of order $n$ is abelian iff every group of order $n$ is cyclic iff $p \not \equiv 1 \pmod q$ and $q \not \equiv 1 \pmod p$.  In particular, every group of order $15$ is cyclic.

**Addendum**: [This](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/Muller06.pdf) 2006 paper of T. Müller is a natural followup.  Rather than describing it myself, let me quote the MathSciNet review.

> It is a popular problem to find for which positive integers n do all groups of order n have a given property (e.g., cyclicity, are abelian, etc.). The article under review contains a contribution to this problem which seems to have escaped notice.
> Define a multiplicative function $\psi$ on the positive integers by letting $\psi(1)=1$, and $\psi(p^ν)=(p^{ν}−1)(p^{ν−1}−1)\cdots(p−1)$ if $p$ is a prime and $ν\geq 1$. The author proves that every group of order $n$ is nilpotent of class at most $c$ if and only if $\operatorname{gcd}(n,\psi(n))=1$ and $n$ is $(c+2)$-power free. Setting $c=\infty$ yields a result of G. Pazderski [Arch. Math. 10 (1959), 331--343; MR0114863 (22 #5681)] describing the case of nilpotency; and setting $c=1$ yields the classic result of L. E. Dickson [Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 6 (1905), no. 2, 198--204; MR1500706] describing the case of abelianness. (Reviewed by [Arturo Magidin](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/742/arturo-magidin))

Comment: @Arturo: thanks, that is a very natural addition.  Indeed, as I was typing up my answer I was wondering what could be said about the nilpotency class of a group which has order a $k$-power free nilpotent number.

Comment: I believe (iii) is due to Tibor Szele (1947) (every group of order n is cyclic iff $\gcd(n, \phi(n)) = 1$). See T. Szele, Uber die endlichen ordnungszahlen zu denen nur eine Gruppe gehirt, Com- menj. Math. Helv., 20 (1947), 265-67.

Comment: @m.k.: 1947 is unexpectedly late, but I might as well include this attribution until/unless something earlier turns up.  Thanks.

Comment: I agree that it is a bit surprising. But Szele is mentioned ("result by Szele") at for example http://oeis.org/A003277 and also http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS/Repository/1.0/Disseminate?view=body&id=pdf_1&handle=euclid.pjm/1102778730 and all other references I have seen for this theorem.

Comment: @m.k. Interesting. Here are all the relevant sequences on Sloane's where more info (references) can be found: [nilpotent numbers A056867](http://oeis.org/A056867); [abelian numbers A051532](http://oeis.org/A051532); [cyclic numbers A003277](http://oeis.org/A003277).

Comment: Both the links are not working.

Answer (score 15):

Hint: Any non-trivial subgroup is a Sylow subgroup. OTOH Sylow theorems tell that there is only one of order 3, and only one of order 5. Therefore there are 15-5-3+1=8 elements that don't belong to a proper subgroup, so...

Comment: Sorry, all. This just happened to be the first question in my candidacy exam (aka quals?) 24 years ago. I couldn't resist.

Comment: Sorry, not getting what does it imply after we have the statement - `Therefore there are 15-5-3+1=8 elements that don't belong to a proper subgroup`. Can you explain please?

Comment: @UnknownMathMan Let $x$ be one of those 8 elements not belonging to either proper subgroup. What is the cyclic subgroup it generates? How many elements in it? You can eliminate all but a single alternative.

Answer (score 13):

In addition to the answers of Hans and Pete: it is well-known that if $n$ is a natural number, there is only one group of order $n$ if and only if $\gcd(n,\varphi(n))=1$. Here $\varphi$ is the Euler totient function. For $n=15$ this applies.

Comment: This may be well-known but I did not know it.  Thanks for the tip.  I found a proof of this here - http://www.jstor.org/stable/2324062?seq=1

Comment: The author even mentions that this result is "well known, but not widely known".

Comment: @Nicky: to say that there is only one group of order $n$ is equivalent to saying that every group of order $n$ is cyclic, so according to my answer this occurs iff $n$ is a squarefree "nilpotent number".  Among square free numbers it is easy to see that the nilpotence condition holds iff $\gcd(n,\varphi(n)) = 1$.

Comment: @Pete, thanks, yet another proof!

Comment: @Hans, I found the result as a student in the late seventies and "published" this in the Problem section of the Nieuw Archief voor de Wiskunde, a Dutch math journal, see Problem NAvW 540, https://bit.ly/3dQmvBM

Answer (score 0):

$G$ has exactly one normal subgroup of order $5$ and order $3$. Let us call them $N_3,N_5$ respectively.
This follows from the **Sylow theorems**.
As $|G| = 15$ but $|N_3| + |N_5| - |\langle 1_G\rangle| = 7$, there is a $g \in G$ that is not $1_G$, nor is it contained in $N_3$ or $N_5$. By closure of $G$ and Lagrange it follows that $\langle g \rangle$ = G.

As an exercise for the interested reader: If $|G| = p\cdot q$ for $p < q$ prime and $p$ not equal $1$ modulo $p$, then the above result holds.
Even the counting argument holds, because $pq > p + q$ for $p,q$ prime and $p < q$.

Answer (score -1):

(Without: Sylow, Cauchy, semi-direct products, cyclic $G/Z(G)$ argument, $\gcd(n,\phi(n))=1$ argument. Just Lagrange and the class equation.)

Firstly, if $|G|=pq$, with $p,q$ distinct primes, say wlog $p>q$, then $G$ can't have $|Z(G)|=p,q$, because otherwise there's no way to accomodate the centralizers of the noncentral elements between the center and the whole group (recall that, for all such $x$, it must strictly hold $Z(G)<C_G(x)<G$).

Next, if in addition $q\nmid p-1$, then a very simple counting argument suffices to rule out the case $|Z(G)|=1$. In fact, if $Z(G)$ is trivial, then the class equation reads:
$$pq=1+kp+lq \tag 1$$
where $k$ and $l$ are the number of conjugacy classes of size $p$ and $q$, respectively.  Now,  there are exactly $lq$ elements of order $p$ (they are the ones in the conjugacy classes of size $q$). Since each subgroup of order $p$ comprises $p-1$ elements of order $p$, and two subgroups of order $p$ intersect trivially, then $lq=m(p-1)$ for some positive integer $m$ such that $q\mid m$ (because by assumption $q\nmid p-1$).
Therefore, $(1)$ yields:
$$pq=1+kp+m'q(p-1) \tag 2$$
for some positive integer $m'$; but then $q\mid 1+kp$, namely $1+kp=nq$ for some positive integer $n$, which plugged into $(2)$ yields:
$$p=n+m'(p-1) \tag 3$$
In order for $m'$ to be a positive integer, it must be $n=1$ (which in turn implies $m'=1$, but this is not essential here). So, $1+kp=q$: contradiction, because $p>q$.

So we are left with $|Z(G)|=pq$, namely $G$ abelian (and hence, incidentally, cyclic).