# About the Order of Groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Is there any theorem that states the all the finite groups of order n are the same? or some sort of theorem that refers to the order of two finite groups?
If anyone can post a reference to this topic will be great...
10x in advance

Comment: This is boldly not true for $n=4$.

Comment: Take any noncommutative group, compare it with the cyclic group of the same order.

Comment: "some sort of theorem that refers to the order of two finite groups"? I'm pretty sure there's more than one such theorem...

Comment: Side remark: On Wikipedia for "finite field" I found: "Any two finite fields with the same number of elements are isomorphic.". But that's about fields.

Comment: @Gerenuk: your comment about finite fields is correct. However, there are very few finite fields: there is a field of order $n$ if and only if $n=p^m$ for some prime $p$, $m\in\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, this is unimaginably not true. In fact, there is a theorem which says that almost the opposite of what you have just said:

> **Theorem:** Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then, there exists only one group (up to isomorphism) of order $n$ if and only if $n=p_1\cdots p_m$ for distinct primes $p_i$, such that $p_i\not\equiv 1\text{ mod }p_j$ for any $i,j$.

This is a standard set of exercises in most algebra textbooks--ask if you'd like an explicit reference.

(I prove this on my blog, [here](http://drexel28.wordpress.com/2011/09/13/a-classification-of-integers-n-for-which-the-only-groups-of-order-n-are-cyclic-pt-i/))

Comment: which is equivalent to $gcd(n,\varphi(n))=1$, where $\varphi$ is the Euler totient.

Comment: See also [cyclic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_number_(group_theory)).

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106085/order-of-cyclic-groups-and-the-euler-phi-function and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67407/group-of-order-15-is-abelian/67469#67469.

Answer (score 5):

Not all groups of order n are the same.

$\mathbb{Z}_6$ and $S_3$ are both of order 6. However $S_3$ has 3 subgroups of order 2, where $\mathbb{Z}_6$ has only one subgroup of order 2.

Therefore they cannot be isomorphic.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the group $C_2\times C_2$ and $C_4$. Both of order $4$ but the latter has an element of order $4$ while the former does not

Comment: I use $C_n$ to denote the cyclic group of $n$ elements.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to read the paper of Besche, Eick and O'Brien http://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~obrien/research/2000.pdf which contains a table of the number of groups of order $n<2001$.