# Reference for classification of small groups

Tags: reference-request, finite-groups

There are various online resources for the classification of groups of small order, such as [this one](http://opensourcemath.org/gap/small_groups.html) or [that one](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Category%3aGroups_of_a_particular_order).

Is there any nice reference in the literature which contains such a classification (say, for orders up to $30$, EDIT: $100$) with detailed proofs? It should only serve as a citation.

Comment: I have thought that classifying small order groups is a routine task and can be used just as you'd use any other routine tools. So, sometimes I see that they are used without proof. But, I cannot find a paper, where, say classification of groups of order 24 is without proof. +1, indeed a nice question.

Comment: I think several books contain a classification of all groups of order less than 60. See also http://math.stackexchange.com/a/142155/589.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This paper contains a classification of groups of order up to 30, with the exception of orders 16 and 24: *Classification of Groups of Small Order* by Michael Van Opstall ([link](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=classification%20of%20small%20groups&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CGcQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.utah.edu%2F~opstall%2Fwritings%2Fclassification.ps&ei=jMuuT7LKJeTR4QTT6qylCQ&usg=AFQjCNF4IKaiDxZVTuoiN_iIHhn1zZCZWg&cad=rja), .ps file). It's not much, and I don't know anything about the paper other than what I've already written, but I think it's a good idea to have the link here in case someone stumbles on this page and doesn't come up with the idea of googling "classification of small groups".

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, the order $16$ already is quite interesting. (M. Wild, Groups Of Order Sixteen Made Easy).