# Are there $n>6$ such that there is exactly one non-abelian group of order $n$ up to isomorphism? This happens with $n=6$ with $S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

In my algebra class, we saw that every non-abelian group of order $6$ is isomorphic to $S_3$. I am curious as to whether this is true for higher orders. The natural answer seems that there are no such orders, but I don't know how to prove this. Thank you for your time.

Comment: 1. Please formulate the question in the body and summarize it in the title 2. What do you mean with "isomorphic to one group G" ? Do you mean that there is exactly one non-abelian group of that order upto isomorphism ?

Comment: An infinite family of examples of such orders (probably not covering all cases) is $ord(G)=pq$ with primes $p<q$ such that $p\mid q-1$.

Comment: @Peter Indeed not all cases, see Martin Brandeburg's answer with $n=75$: there's no element of order $3$ in $GL(1,3)$ and only one conjugacy class of elements of order $3$ in $GL(2,3)$.

Comment: I meant $GL(1,5)$ and $GL(2,5)$.

Comment: @Peter I edited the question according to your suggestion. Thanks for the insights.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are many more such numbers. They can be generated with the following piece of [GAP code](https://www.gap-system.org/).

```
numberNonAbelianGroups := function(n)
  local allGroups, abelianGroups;
  allGroups := AllSmallGroups(n);
  abelianGroups := AllSmallGroups(n,IsAbelian);
  return Size(allGroups) - Size(abelianGroups);
end;

numbersWithOneNonAbelianGroup := function(limit)
  local n;
  return Filtered([1..limit],n -> numberNonAbelianGroups(n) = 1);
end;
```

The output of `numbersWithOneNonAbelianGroup(100);` is:

`[ 6, 10, 14, 21, 22, 26, 34, 38, 39, 46, 55, 57, 58, 62, 74, 75, 82, 86, 93, 94 ]`

This is the OEIS sequence [A060650](https://oeis.org/A060650), about which probably not much is known. The related sequence [A060689](https://oeis.org/A060689) counts the non-abelian groups of a given order.

As remarked in the comments, an infinite subsequence is formed by the products $p \cdot q$ of two primes with $p \mid q-1$ (see [SE/881971](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/881971)). The examples $\leq 100$ are

`[ 6, 10, 14, 21, 22, 26, 34, 38, 39, 46, 55, 57, 58, 62, 74, 82, 86, 93, 94 ]`

so these only miss out $75$. The next examples in the sequence which are not products of two primes are $105, 165, 195, 231, 285, 357, 363, 385, 429, 483$ (all of which are products of three primes).

The sequence is contained in [A060652](https://oeis.org/A060652), the orders for which *at least one* group is non-abelian. These can be classified  explicitly by means of their prime factorization (see also [SE/227628](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227628/what-are-the-situations-in-which-any-group-of-order-n-is-abelian#227655)). So this is a necessary condition.