# Proving cyclic group via Euler totient function

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclic-groups

I want to prove the following theorem

> Let $G$ be a finite group such that $(|G|,\phi(|G|))=1$ (where $\phi$ is the totient function), then $G$ is cyclic.

I used this theorem so far, but suddenly I want to prove this theorem, what can be the nice approach for proving this theorem?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106085/order-of-cyclic-groups-and-the-euler-phi-function