# A condition for a finite group to be abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I know that a group of order $pq$ where $p < q$ and $p \not\mid q-1$ is abelian (in particular it is cyclic), and that a group of order $p^2q^2$ where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes, $q \not\mid p^2-1$, and $p \not\mid q^2-1$ is abelian.  I have attempted to generalize this (in what seems like the obvious way) and would appreciate it if someone could confirm the validity (or lack thereof) of my "conjecture".

Let $G$ be a group with $|G|=p^nq^m$ where $p$, $q$ are distinct primes and $n, m \ge 1$.  Furthermore, assume that $p \not\mid q^k-1$ and $q \not\mid p^k-1$ for $1 \le k \le m$ and $1 \le k \le n$, respectively.  Then $G$ is abelian.

Proof: Every divisor of $|G|$ is of the form $p^sq^t$ with $0 \le s \le n$ and $0 \le t \le m$.  If $s \ne 0$ then $p\mid p^sq^t$ so that $p^sq^t \equiv 0 \,\,\mbox{mod}\,p$, and similarly if $t \ne 0$ then $p^sq^t \equiv 0 \,\,\mbox{mod}\,q$.  Therefore we will now assume that $s=0$ or $t=0$.  Let $1 \le k \le n$.  If $p \not\mid q^k-1$ for all $k$, then $q^k \not\equiv 1 \,\, \mbox{mod}\,p$ and if $q \not\mid p^k-1$ for all $k$ then $p^k \not\equiv 1\, \mbox{mod} \,q$.  Therefore $1$ is the only divisor of $|G|$ that is congruent to $1 \,\mbox{mod}\,p$ and $1 \, \mbox{mod}\,q$.

It follows by Sylow's Third Theorem that $G$ has only one Sylow $p$-subgroup and one Sylow $q$-subgroup.  In addition, each of these subgroups is normal.  Clearly the order of their product is $|G|$ and they intersect trivially.  Furthermore, it can be shown (see proof of Theorem 24.6 in Contemporary Abstract Algebra, Gallian, 5th ed.) that all elements in these subgroups commute.  Therefore, $G$ is abelian.

Comment: As has been pointed out, the error is the assumption that the Sylow subgroups are themselves abelian. If you want a full characterization of the "abelian numbers", you can find that and more in [this answer by Pete L. Clark](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/67469/742).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't true. $G = H_5 \times H_7$, where $H_p$ is the Heisenberg group mod $p$, is a counterexample. See Keith Conrad's notes [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/groupsp3.pdf).

I don't know what Theorem 24.6 of Gallian's book states, but groups of order $p^k$ are not guaranteed to be abelian unless $k \leq 2$.

Comment: Why the change in counterexample?  And where exactly do things go wrong with my attempted generalization?

The part of the proof in Gallian that I referred to just shows that the elements of two trivially intersecting normal subgroups commute.

Comment: I changed the counterexample to a standard group of order $p^3$. And it is true that the elements of the two distinct normal $p$-Sylows commute with each other. However, the $p$-Sylows are not commutative _themselves_.

Comment: ...hence failure in the case of an exponent greater than 3.  I understand now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

"The Abelian orders (or Abelian numbers): n such that every group of order n is Abelian" is at https://oeis.org/A051532, where it gives conditions on the primes dividing $n$.