# For which $n$, $G$ is abelian?

Tags: finite-groups, abelian-groups

My question is:

> For Which  natural numbers $n$, a finite group $G$ of order $n$ is an abelian group?

Obviouslyو for $n≤4$ and when $n$ is a prime number, we have $G$ is abelian. Can we consider any other restrictions or conditions for $n$ to have the above statement or the group itself should have certain structure as well? Thanks.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67407/group-of-order-15-is-abelian/67469#67469

Comment: @lhf: Thank you for this great article. Thanks.

Comment: It's very nice that this natural question and others along that line have a beautiful arithmetical answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Every group of order $n$ is abelian iff $n$ is a cubefree nilpotent number.

We say that $n$ is a *nilpotent number* if when we factor $n = p_1^{a_1} \cdots p_r^{a_r}$ we have 
$p_i^k \not \equiv 1 \bmod{p_j}$ for all $1 \leq k \leq a_i$.

(adapted from [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67407/group-of-order-15-is-abelian/67469#67469) by [Pete Clark](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/299/pete-l-clark).)

Comment: Thanks for above link. After these days, this answer has been fresh yet. You know; I found a problem which was solved by J.D.Dixon in his book (Problems in Group Theory) citing: A group of order $n$ which $(n,\phi(n))=1$ is abelian. Is this the same as Pete Clark pointed in that link? Thanks and sorry for backing on this problem again. $\phi$ is Euler's function.