# Facts about Abelian Groups and group order.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

I look for some theorems which tell us about the relation between the property of being abelian for groups and the order of the group.

I think these theorems are provided in a second course of group theory or more advanced courses.  At this stage, however, I'm interested in knowing some of these theorems without the details of proofs of this theorems.

I hope that you can give me some of these theorems!

Thanks.

Comment: One such theorem is if the order of the group is prime, then the group is cyclic, hence abelian.

Comment: You should also note that you cannot conclude anything about the order from the group being abelian, as there are abelian groups of any (finite) order (and probably any infinite order as well, but there are set theorists around so I'm being careful). So any result has to deduce that groups of certain orders (maybe with some other properties) are abelian, as in Fredrik's example.

Comment: @FredrikMeyer , yes , i know this corollary , it's proved after studying lagrange theorem, do you know other theorems ?

Comment: There's the Fundamental Theorem of Finite Abelian Groups: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Fundamental_Theorem_of_Finite_Abelian_Groups

Comment: $G$ is abelian if $|G|=p^2$ and $p$ is prime, [from here](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Group_of_Order_Prime_Squared_is_Abelian)

Comment: Theorem: If $|G|=pq$, where $p<q$ are primes such that $q\not\equiv1\pmod p$, then $G$ is cyclic, hence abelian.

Comment: @ToddWilcox, that is not what is wanted. He wants to be able to say, "If $|G|=n$, then, by stuff I only can figure about $n$, I know that $G$ is abelian.

Comment: Can be of interest: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/31553/finite-nonabelian-groups-of-odd-order

Answer (score 9):

Here are some facts.  Assume all groups below are finite.

- All finite abelian groups look like this: $\mathbb{Z}_{p_1^{e_1}}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{p_2^{e_2}}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{p_3^{e_3}}\oplus \cdots \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{p_n^{e_n}}$, where the $p_i$ are not necessarily distinct.
- $\mathbb{Z}_{pq}\cong \mathbb{Z}_p\oplus\, \mathbb{Z}_q$ if and only if $p$ and $q$ are coprime.
- A group $G$ is cyclic if and only if it has exactly one subgroup of order $d$ for every divisor $d$ of $|G|$.
- Lagrange's theorem states that whenever $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, the order of $H$ divides the order of $G$.  The converse does not hold in general, but it does for abelian groups - that is, for every divisor $d$ of $|G|$, there is a subgroup of order $d$ in $G$.
- If $3/4$ths or more of a group's elements have order $2$, the group is abelian.  In particular, if every element in a group has order $2$, that group is abelian.  (*Note*: the latter obviously follows from the former, but is proved much more easily by itself.)
- The derived subgroup and inner automorphism group of an abelian group have order $1$.
- Of all groups of order $p^e$, groups which look like $\underbrace{\mathbb{Z}_p\oplus \mathbb{Z}_p \oplus \cdots \oplus \mathbb{Z}_p}_{\text{e times}}$ have the largest number of subgroups.  Groups which look like $\mathbb{Z}_{p^e}$ have the fewest.  (This includes nonabelian groups.)
- The order of the automorphism groups of the last bullet point are $\prod_{k=0}^{e-1}p^e-p^k$ and $p^{e-1}(p-1)$, respectively.  In general the order of the automorphism group of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is [$\varphi(n)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).
- If a group is simple and solvable, it is cyclic of prime order.

Comment: $|ab|=lcm(|a|,|b|)$ is wrong (take for instance $a=b^{-1}$).

Comment: Some people are more familiar with $\times$ than $\oplus$, but if you've never seen it before, $A\oplus B$ and $A\times B$ are isomorphic. (things get more complicated if there are "infinitely many" $\oplus$ signs)

Comment: @EricStucky I hate to admit it but pretty much the only reason I use $\oplus$ instead of $\times$ is I think it looks cooler.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber Although they do have different meanings. One is a "coproduct" and one is a "product". The fact that they coincide (they are a "biproduct") has to do with the fact that the category of abelian groups is an abelian category.

Answer (score 4):

One can classify those integers $n$ for which every group of order $n$ is abelian, see [here](http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/known-math/97/clt.numbers), the last answer by Robin Chapman. This has also appeared [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67407/group-of-order-15-is-abelian/67469#67469) and [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156487/for-which-n-g-is-abelian) on math.stackexchange.

Comment: The condition you have given classifies $n$ for which every group of order $n$ is cyclic. For example, for $p$ prime every group of order $p^2$ is abelian but $p^2$ and $\phi(p^2)$ are not coprime.

Comment: Ok, I copied from one of the linked threads.