# Is that truth that any group of order 224 is abelian?

Tags: group-theory

I'm trying to solve this problem which is connected with Group Theory.

As I've already noticed any group of order 224 must be non-simple. How then I should check if it is abelian or not (in general case)?

Comment: If a group has even order (greater than $4$) then it need not be abelian (think dihedral).

Comment: Yeah, you're right. But in this case we know additionally that it is not simple.

Comment: How does that change what I just wrote?

Comment: It may restrict the properties of a particular group.

Comment: @lhf, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every group of order $n$ is abelian iff $n$ is a cubefree nilpotent number.

Therefore, not all groups of $224$ can be abelian because $224=2^5 \cdot 7$ is not cubefree.

(You don't even need to known what a nilpotent number is.)

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/156492/589 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227628/what-are-the-situations-in-which-any-group-of-order-n-is-abelian

Answer (score 1):

The dihedral group $D_{112}$ has order $224$ and is not abelian. So it is not true.

We also know that every group of order $224$ is solvable, but this doesn't matter here. Indeed, all dihedral groups are solvable. We only need to find one non-abelian group of order $224$ to refute the claim that all groups of order $224$ are abelian.