# A group of order 561 is cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Prove that any group of order 561 is cyclic.

Comment: As you are a new user I would like to tell you that : It would not be enough to just write the question to get a reply... please explain what you have tried?

Comment: 15 not prim but is cyclic.

Comment: @Magdiragdag : fine fine :)

Comment: What would be prime factorization of $561$?

Comment: @ayoob: At least you should describe your background, what did you learn and what difficulties did you encountered so that you know what hints and answers should be given.

Comment: we shoud use this theorem

Comment: N(H)/C(H) -----> AUT(H)      normalizer - central theorem

Comment: What theorem? But let me guess, the third Sylow theorem. Still, you could at least formulate that theorem.

Comment: DO you mind to edit your question to "Use N/C theorem"...?

Comment: I don't understand how this question has 6 upvotes (as of now).

Answer (score 15):

In general, there is only one group of order $n$ iff gcd$(n,\varphi(n))=1$. Of course such a group must be necessarily cyclic. 561 satisfies the condition.

Comment: Isn't this more advanced for a beginner?

Comment: ?????????????????????????

Comment: i cofused about this

Comment: @ayoob - what is your confusion?

Comment: @Praphulla - well if a proof is given by *mathematics2x2life* making use of Sylow's Theorems, what exactly is the definition of advanced then? If you know Sylow Theory, then the criterium as mentioned is not far away from an actual proof.

Comment: @NickyHekster : I have not seen this statement before.. It may be advanced or not.. I can not comment anything on that.. All i could say is "thank you for giving another exercise which looks so beautiful" :)

Comment: @Praphulla - OK, it has been discussed many times here at this Math StackExchange. In fact, there is a paper  of Pakianathan and Shankar (2000) which gives characterizations of the set of positive integers n such that every group of order n is (i) cyclic, (ii) abelian, or (iii) nilpotent. See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67407/group-of-order-15-is-abelian/67757#67757 !!

Comment: @NickyHekster : Thank you for the link :) That would help me i believe..

Comment: @Praphulla - I always find it extremely intriguing that from *the order only* of a finite group one can read of some special properties!

Comment: tank you dear for this

Comment: @NickyHekster This is really a neat fact. I had never heard of it either, until now.

Comment: @rschwieb Yes, I think so too! And the nice thing of it it is so simple and you will never forget it!

Comment: See also [here](http://mathoverflow.net/q/148731/6085) for some references.

Comment: Wow! This is a very interesting theorem! Thank you for sharing it!

Comment: I do not see why this fact tells us that the given group is necessarily cyclic, could you explain please?

Comment: Well, $561=3 \cdot 11 \cdot 17$. So $\varphi(561)=2^6 \cdot 5$, whence relatively prime to $561$. And for any natural number $n$ there is always the cyclic group $C_n$ of that order….

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, $|G|=561=3.11.17$. By Sylow III, $n_{11}\mid 3.17$ and $n_{11}\equiv 1\pmod {11}$; so, $n_{11}=1$. Say $K$ the $11$-Sylow subgroup. Since it is normal, $K$ is the union of conjugacy classes of $G$, with as many singletons as the order of $|K\cap Z(G)|$. But, by Lagrange, $|K\cap Z(G)|=1$ or $11$, and the former option is ruled out because there isn't any union of noncentral conjugacy classes of $G$ summing to size $10$. Therefore $K$ is central, and being $G/K$ cyclic (as $3\nmid 17-1$), then $G$ is abelian and finally cyclic (take the product of any three elements of order $3$, $11$ and $17$, respectively).