# Why Of course such a group must be necessarily cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Why the formula given in the answer here tells us that this group must be cyclic?

[A group of order 561 is cyclic.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/605227/a-group-of-order-561-is-cyclic)

Here is the answer there:

In general, there is only one group of order $n$ iff gcd$(n,\varphi(n))=1$. Of course such a group must be necessarily cyclic. 561 satisfies the condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because obviously there exists a cyclic group of order $n$ (namely $\{ 0, 1, 2, \ldots, n-1 \}$ with addition modulo $n$), so if there is a unique group of that order, it must be the cyclic one.

Comment: But I am trying to apply this result to a group of order 255 which is not prime.

Comment: Oh, are you using the fact that $\mathbb Z_n$ is a cyclic group for any $n$?

Comment: Yes. $\phantom{}$

Comment: Do you know any resource for a rigor proof for this fact  mentioned in the solution? Is it a new fact?

Comment: I think it is given in a link in the comments

Comment: @Brain, no it is not "a new fact". It is a theorem of Dickson that is over 100 years old. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/67469/742).