# Group of order 15

Tags: group-theory

Using the fact that if $a$ and $b$ are two distinct elements of order $5$, either $\langle a \rangle \cap \langle b \rangle =\{e\}$ or $\langle a \rangle = \langle b \rangle$, show that $G$ must have an element of order $3$.
Do not assume that $G$ is a cyclic group.

Comment: The last question was concerning a cyclic group, I cannot assume now that it is cyclic.

Comment: Have you heard of Lagrange's Theorem?

Comment: Yes I've heard of Lagrange's theorem but am struggling to apply it to this particular question

Comment: @Algebra We already [know](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1211689/how-many-different-groups-of-order-15-there-are) that every group of order $15$ is cyclic. So you can use now that it is cyclic.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde- ok thanks

Answer (score 3):

If $|G|=15$ the possible orders of the elements are 1,3,5,15.

If there is an element of order $15$ then its fifth power has order 3. So suppose there are no elements of order 15.

If there are no elements of order 3 then we have 1 element of order 1 and 14 elements of order 5. But the cyclic groups generated by the elements of order 5 do not (as you know) overlap except at the identity. So we will have $1+4k$ elements in total, where $k$ is the number of distinct cyclic subgroups of order 5.

15 is not of this form.

etc.

Comment: Thank you @ancientmathematician - that's helped a lot

Comment: I thought you were panicking. Have a break.