# Is the group $\mathbb Z/3 \times \mathbb Z/5$ cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

In understanding if there exist an abelian group of order $15$ that is not cyclic,  I came up with this example: the direct product $\mathbb{Z}/3 \times \mathbb{Z}/5$. I know that this group is abelian, but I'm unsure if its cyclic or not.

If I can find one element in this set where I multiply it by a number that is not $15$, and I get $(\overline{0},\overline{0})$ then it can't be cyclic and I'm done, I think this is the case at least, is my logic correct, or would I need some number less than 15, multiply every element in this set by a number strictly less than 15, and get $(\overline{0},\overline{0})$. If this is the case then no such example exists.

Comment: There is only one group of order $15$ up to isomorphism. It is cyclic.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1211689/362009

Comment: More generally, for any natural number $n$, if $n$ and $\phi(n)$ are relatively prime, there is only one group of order $n$ up to isomorphism and it is cyclic.

Comment: For further proofs, see [wiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Group_of_Order_15_is_Cyclic_Group).

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}/3 \times \mathbb{Z}/5$ is cyclic by the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: The linked question and answer involve Sylow’s theorems and other more sophisticated techniques that IMO make it a different kind of question than the one the OP is asking.

Comment: [The mother of the other linked thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/67407/11619).

Comment: You can try prove that $\mathbb Z / m\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z$ is cyclic iff $\text{gcd} (m,n) =1$. Try Bezout's lemma.

Comment: Your logic should be:" If I can find an element such that multiplied by a number from $1$ to $14$ I do not get $(0,0)$ then the group is cyclic".  There are many such elements, one example is $(1,1)$.

Comment: Why did you delete [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4285559/742)? If you are just trying to hide your tracks, then kindly take your efforts elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: What is the order of the element $(1,1) \in \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_5?$ (there is a general formula for the order of an element in a direct product, but you can check it what the order is here by hand if you don't know this formula). What can you conclude about the group?

It can be shown that any group of order $15$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$. This is usually proven by Sylow theory.