# If $G$ and $G'$ are two finite group of same cardinal, then $G\cong G'$.

Tags: group-theory

I have to prove that if $G$ and $G'$ are two finites group of same cardinal, then they are isomorphic.

Actually, it looks obvious. Suppose $G=\{g_1,...,g_n\}$ and $G'=\{h_1,...,h_n\}$. Does the homomorphism $g_i\longmapsto h_i$ work ?

Comment: This is not true in general.,  For example $\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$ is not isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$.

Comment: There must be another assumption - I'm guessing both groups are cyclic?

Comment: For cyclic, it's definitely true.  Map generator to generator.

Comment: Is it possible you meant "sets" instead of "groups"?  As everyone is pointing out, the statement is far from true for groups.

Comment: I am pretty sure there are at least two non-isomorphic groups of any cardinality except for $0,1$ and $p$ (where $p$ is prime).

Comment: Also, why do you think $g_i \to h_i$ is a homomorphism?

Comment: @dREaM: Overly fancy by a lot, but one can use Upward Lowenheim-Skolem.

Comment: @dREaM : there is [only 1 group of order 15](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67407/group-of-order-15-is-abelian), isn't it?

Comment: Oh, you seem to be right.

Comment: I think we also need $pq$ where $p<q$ and $q$ is not congruent to $1\bmod p$.

Comment: @dREaM : it is possible to [prove](https://yiminge.wordpress.com/2009/01/22/all-groups-of-order-n-are-cyclic-iff/) that the number of groups of order $n$ (up to isomorphism) is $1$ iff $(n,\phi(n))=1$. Therefore, I think the condition should be $(n,\phi(n))>1$.

Comment: Why are people downvoting this person?  They asked a legitimate question and showed their attempted answer.  So downvoting without constructive criticism is rude in my opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not true in general.,  For example $\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$ is not isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$.

You probably also need to assume both groups are cyclic.  In that case you can write one as $\{a,a^2,\dots,a^n\}$ and the other as $\{b,b^2,\dots,b^n\}$.  Then map $a\mapsto b$ to get the isomorphism.

Comment: nice......+1, what is condition of cyclicity

Comment: Ok, in fact I had to say if this assertion is wrong or false. And in fact it false for the reason you said. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

$\Bbb Z_6$ is commutative and $S_3$ isn't, and both have six elements.

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't work since this result is wrong. For example $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$. To prove that there are not isomorphic, simply remark that $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ has an element of order $4$ whereas $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ has no element of order $4$.