# What information can one obtain from the size of a finite group?

Tags: finite-groups

Given $n = \lvert G \rvert$ then the factorization of $n$ can sometimes give information about the group $G$. For example if $n$ is prime we know that the group is the cyclic group $C_n$.  If $n$ is the power of a prime then we know that $G$ is nilpotent. Are there cases like these that assert that $G$ has certain properties knowing $n$? For example all groups of size $100$ are solvable, for which $n$ can one say the same?

Comment: Have you heard about the [Sylow theorems](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems)?

Comment: What properties to they tell us about the structure of the group apart from the existence of some subgroups?

Comment: @Arthur In the case $n=100$ they tell us that they have a normal subgroup of order $25$;

Comment: Existence and number of certain subgroups is an important part of a group's structure.

Comment: Do you mean normal subgroups or ore there other importtant cases?

Comment: I mean other cases too. It doesn't directly help you make a multiplication table, but it _is_ important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We say that $n$ is a *nilpotent number* if when we factor $n = p_1^{a_1} \cdots p_r^{a_r}$ we have 
$p_i^k \not \equiv 1 \bmod{p_j}$ for all $1 \leq k \leq a_i$.

Then

- Every group of order $n$ is nilpotent iff $n$ is a nilpotent number.
- Every group of order $n$ is abelian iff $n$ is a cubefree nilpotent number.
- Every group of order $n$ is cyclic iff $n$ is a squarefree nilpotent number.

(adapted from [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67407/group-of-order-15-is-abelian/67469#67469) by [Pete Clark](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/299/pete-l-clark))

For solvable numbers, see the last theorem in the paper [Nilpotent and solvable numbers](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.30.4997&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Pakianathan and Shankar:

[image]

(also J. Pakianathan and K. Shankar, [Nilpotent numbers](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2589118), *Amer. Math. Monthly*, 107, August– September 2000, 631–634)