# Non-cyclic numbers that are not the order of any capable group

Tags: group-theory

A group $G$ is said to be capable if there is some group $H$ for which $H/Z(H)$ is isomorphic to $G$.

It is known that the only capable cyclic group is the trivial group. So, if $n$ is a cyclic number (i.e., the cyclic group is the only group of order $n$) other than $1$, then there is no group whose center has index $n$.

But is there a non-cyclic number $n$ for which there is no group whose center has index $n$ (or equivalently, there is no capable group of order $n$)?

Checking small values of $n$:

- $n=4$: The Klein four-group is capable (arising as the central quotient of the quaternion group).
- $n=6$: The symmetric group $S_3$ is capable (arising as its own central quotient, as it is centerless).
- $n=8$: A finite abelian group is known to be capable if and only if it is isomorphic to a finite direct sum $\mathbb{Z}_{n_1} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{n_2} \oplus ... \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{n_k}$ where $n_1 \mid n_2 \mid ... \mid n_{k-1} = n_k$ (i.e., the last two invariant factors coincide). So, the elementary abelian $2$-group of order $8$ is capable.
- $n=9$: The elementary abelian $3$-group of order $9$ is capable by the same argument.
- $n=10$: The dihedral group of order $10$ is centerless, so it is capable.
- $n=12$: The alternating group $A_4$ is centerless, so it is capable.
- $n=14$: The dihedral group of order $14$ is centerless, so it is capable.
- $n=16$: The elementary abelian $2$-group of order $16$ is capable by the same argument as for orders $8$ and $9$.
- $n=18$: The dihedral group of order $18$ is centerless, so it is capable.
- $n=20$: There is a centerless group of order $20$, which is then also capable.

So far, no such $n$ has been found yet.

To find numbers that are not the order of centerless groups, look up [A216594](https://oeis.org/A216594) and [A056867](https://oeis.org/A056867) in the OEIS. The smallest number in A056867 that is neither a cyclic number nor a power of a prime is $45$, while the smallest number in A216594 is $28$.

This means that the smallest $n$ that answers the question (if it exists) could be $28$ or $45$ or another member of A216594 or A056867.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken,  $D_{56}$, the dihedral group,  rules out $28.$

Comment: All the $n!$'s are ruled out.   $S_n$ is centerless,  $n\ge3.$

Comment: Dihedral groups wipe out all evens.

Answer (score 5):

A number $n$ with prime factorization
$$n=p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_r^{a_r}$$
where the $p_i$ are distinct primes and $a_i\geq 1$ for all $i$, is a *nilpotent number* if and only if for all $1\leq i,j\leq r$, and $1\leq k\leq a_i$, $p_i^k\not\equiv 1\pmod{p_j}$.

A theorem of Pazderski from 1959 shows that every group of order $n$ is nilpotent if and only if $n$ is a nilpotent number. It is a theorem of Dickson from 1905 that every group of order $n$ is abelian if and only if $n$ is a cube free nilpotent number. It is a theorem of
Szele from 1947 that every group of order $n$ is cyclic if and only if it is a squarefree nilpotent number. (See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/67469/742))

It is a corollary to a Theorem of Baer that a finite abelian group is capable if and only if it is not cyclic, and its two largest invariant factors are equal. That is, if $A$ is a finite abelian group written in the form
$$A= C_{m_1}\oplus\cdots\oplus C_{m_r},\qquad m_1\mid m_2\mid\cdots\mid m_r,$$
with $C_k$ the cyclic group of order $k$, the $A$ is capable if and only if $r\gt 1$ and $m_{r-1}=m_r$.

So take $n=45 =3^2\times 5$. By Szele's theorem, not every group of order $45$ is cyclic. By Dickson's theorem every group of order $45$ is abelian. And the two abelian groups of order $45$ are $C_{45}$ and $C_3\oplus C_{15}$, with neither capable by Baer's characterization of capable groups that are direct sums of cyclic groups.

In fact, $45$ is the smallest non-cyclic number in which all groups are not capable.

For $k\geq 2$, the dihedral group of order $4k$ has center cyclic of order $2$, and the central quotient is the dihedral group of order $2k$. So every even number greater than $2$ is the order of a capable group, namely the dihedral group of that order.

For prime powers $p^k$, $k\geq 2$, we can always take the elementary abelian $p$-group of that order, which is capable.

For orders of the form $pq$ with $p$ and $q$ primes, and which are not cyclic numbers, the nonabelian group of order $pq$ has trivial center, so it is equal to its own central quotient.

For orders less than $45$:

1. For even number $2k$, $2\leq k\leq 22$, there is a capable group of order $2k$.
2. The values $2$, $3$, $5$, $7$, $11$, $13$, $15$, $17$, $19$, $23$, $29$, $31$, $33$, $35$, $37$, $41$, and $43$ are [cyclic numbers](https://oeis.org/A003277).
3. The values $9$, $25$, and $27$ are prime powers that are not prime, so there are capable groups of that order.
4. The nonabelian groups of order $21$ and $39$ are centerless and capable.

So $45$ is the smallest number that is not a cyclic number, but in which every group of order $45$ is not capable.

It it not hard to show that a finite nilpotent group is capable if and only if its $p$-parts are capable. Thus, for nilpotent numbers $n$, every group of that order is not capable if and only if there is a prime $p$ such that $p\mid n$ but $p^2\nmid n$.

And any number of the form $p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_r^{a_r}$, with $p_i$ distinct primes and $a_j\geq 2$ for all $j$ is the order of a capable group (just take a direct product of the corresponding elementary abelian groups).

I would think that non-nilpotent numbers are always the order of a capable groups, but I would not necessarily be surprised if it turns out that this is not the case. I haven't really thought it through.

Comment: Are groups of order a nilpotent number nilpotent?

Comment: @metoo As it says in the linked-to post, every group of order $n$ is nilpotent if and only if $n$ is a nilpotent number. That's a theorem of Pazderski (1959)

Comment: For the conjecture in the last paragraph, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4873980/is-every-member-of-a216594-the-order-of-a-capable-group.

Comment: Unfortunately, not every non-nilpotent number is the order of a capable group, as the answer to the question linked in the above comment shows. For example, the non-nilpotent number $105$ is not the order of any capable group.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang Calling it a "conjecture" gives me too much credit. It was little more than a first impression. I even said I wouldn't be surprised if it wasn't the case. And I don't need up-to-the-minute updates.

Comment: Well, that was petty. Removed the upvote and then downvoted. Because I complained about pinging me in comments with updates that should be in the post itself, not as comments to an answer.